# Find matrix of a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image]

The standard method of T(u1) = a11.u1 + a12.u2 +...+ a1n.un is proving to be too tedious.
Is there any other way to solve this?

Anything on the lines of change of basis matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis andlet$$M=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&3\\0&2&-1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$(the columns of $M$ are the entries of the $V_i$'s). Then the matrix that you are looking for is $M.A.M^{-1}$.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this method? Any link you can provide me so that I can know how the method works in general?

Comment: @AJ_ This is taught in any Linear Algebra cours. If you want link, try [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Change_of_basis).